# How can I make a line of vertices round?

Tags: vertices

I have a straight line of vertices and I don't know how to make them be arranged in a circular shape such as the top part of a dome.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: do you want to bake just one line of vertices round? Or do you want to take a flat edge, and bridge the edge in to a round edge?

Comment: Well, either way would be good. I just need to create a semi-circular shape.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't mind not using the original vertices, I would add a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *>Add circle*) in *edit mode*, so that it's added straight into the current object.

If you want to keep the existing verts, you could try using the *To sphere* operator (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), or the *circle* operator in the bundled loop tools addon (you will have to enable in *User prefs > Addons*).

[image]

In the above example I first rotated one of the end verts with proportional editing enabled (<kbd>O</kbd>), to give it a semi-circular shape. This makes it easier for the *circle* operator

Comment: It should be added that, when using LoopTools > Circle across a Mirror Modifier, the routine will use only the one side as input, so the results will not be as expected.

Comment: @Ben good point; in that situation you can put the 3D cursor in the actual center of the sphere (e.g. by selecting two opposing vertices and snapping the cursor to selected (shift+S)), then set the cursor as pivot (numpad .). To sphere at least will then be centered as expected, I'm not sure about looptools (and am currently on mobile, so I can't test atm)

Comment: I will give it a go, if that works out, it would really sweeten my day!

Comment: Loop Tools does not seem to give a hoot, but To Sphere works just as advertised!